# XAML - Automation ID for ComboBox elements in DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: wpf, xaml, automation

To start off, the method that I'm using for automating individual elements of ComboBox is as follows:

```
<ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId"
                Value="{Binding ProviderName}" />
    </Style>
</ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

`ProviderName` is bound to the ComboBox's `DisplayMemberPath` property.

My problem is that `ItemContainerStyle` does not seem to be available when trying to modify `DataGridComboBoxColumn` so that the elements of the combo box contained within also have automation IDs.

Has anyone come across a method for doing so?

I'm still toying around with different ideas, so if I come across any meaningful results I'll post them.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimenting, I managed to get it to work by setting the `EditingElementStyle`.

Here's the XAML:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId"
                            Value="{Binding ProviderName}" />
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
```